# How to sort in array of object - CouchBase

Tags: arrays, database, sorting, couchbase, sql++

Hi currently I want to sort array of object, I use ARRAY_SORT function, it will use the first field of object to sort & it work well if every object has the same JSON structure. If one element in array has different JSON structure, the result is incorrect.

The query I use :

```
SELECT ARRAY_SORT(c.student) as student FROM Class c
```

**Result :**

```
"student": [
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Kenny35"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Kenny35"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Kenny35"
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Kenny35"
  },
  {
    "hobby": "video game",
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Kenny35"
  }
]
```

How can I specify property of object in array for ARRAY_SORT function ?

Answer (score 1):

dev,
Objects are first compared by length/size of the object, then followed by fields in the object.
http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/comparisonops.html

That is the only collation supported now.
-Prasad

Answer (score 0):

You can issue a query and use ORDER BY.

```
SELECT *
FROM Class c
UNNEST c.student s
ORDER BY ...
```