# How to sort inner array of document which is retrieved by using document ID

Tags: couchbase, sql++

```
SELECT * from bucket b WHERE meta().id = 'PROFILE_LIST'
```

Above query gives below result, but in addition I need the inner array matchingProfile_ should come in sorted order of createdDate. Is it possible? if yes, What changes I have to make for this query to achieve the same?

```
[
   {
    "matchingProfile_": [
            {
              "createdDate": "2020-09-26T02:30:00",
              "contactDetails_": {
                "address_": {
                  "addressLine1_": "",
                  "addressLine2_": "",
                  "city_": ""
                 }
            },
            {
              "createdDate": "2020-09-27T02:30:00",
              "contactDetails_": {
                "address_": {
                  "addressLine1_": "",
                  "addressLine2_": "",
                  "city_": ""
                 }
            }
    ]
   }
]
```

Comment: In general, if you already know the document ID, I'd recommend not using a N1QL query to get it. It's just adding overhead. Use the key/value API instead, if you can.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort in array of object - CouchBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39911282/how-to-sort-in-array-of-object-couchbase)

Comment: No, @MatthewGroves, Because whenever I was searching using meta().id, I was not able to UNNEST and give sort by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use subquery expression preserve whole document structure and sort array on desired way (even use complete SQL functionality)

```
SELECT b.*, 
      (SELECT RAW mp 
       FROM b.matchingProfile_ AS mp 
       ORDER BY mp.createdDate) AS matchingProfile_
FROM bucket AS b USE KEYS 'PROFILE_LIST';
```